# Can't install anything on Kali Linux

Tags: installation, wireshark, kali-linux, package-management, dependencies

Whenever I try to install anything on Kali Linux I get the same error.
For example running `sudo apt-get -f install alien` outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 alien : Depends: debhelper (>= 7) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: rpm (>= 2.4.4-2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: rpm2cpio but it is not going to be installed
 tcpdump : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 tshark : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 wireshark-common : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
 wireshark-qt : Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing what the output says. Instead of running `sudo apt-get -f install alien` to fix problems with only the alien package type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

(with no packages)

From the output of `man apt-get`

```
-f, --fix-broken  
    Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. 
    This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages  
    to permit APT to deduce a likely solution.
```